# How to import querytable from web page and assign it to a variable (instead of address the entire table into a spreadsheet)?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I'm having some troubles with Excel VBA and would like to see if someone can help me.

I'm importing a table from a Web Page and I want to know if is it possible to assign the table to a variable, instead of addressing the table to a spreadsheet.

The commands I'm using is that:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www4.bcb.gov.br/pec/poupanca/poupanca.asp", _ 
     Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Doing like this the table is imported to cell A1.
I would rather prefer to import into a variable to use in my code, without plotting all the data from the table into the spreadsheet.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querytable is not intended to store the information in a variable but to write to the sheet.

If you want to use a variable consider a method such as follows (GET request where table is then located and put in variable `hTable`)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim sResponse As String, hTable As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://www4.bcb.gov.br/pec/poupanca/poupanca.asp", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    With CreateObject("htmlFile")
        .Write sResponse
        Set hTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
    End With
    MsgBox TypeName(hTable)
End Sub
```

Note: Method is adapted from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834903/6241235). Original author of general method I cannot attribute.